# Ussd Handling on Android 8+ without accessibility

Tags: android, telephonymanager, ussd

I've been trying to handle multi-session USSD response using the new sendUssdRequest Telephony API for like a week now. So far I've been able to see only propositions for accessibility which I don't consider an option. Whenever the operation does not end with the network closing the transaction, I just get the failure callback invoked with useless information.

I would like to hear of someone who dealt with this before and love if someone has overcome it to get at least the raw message sent from the carrier operator.

Note: Please I am not interested with accessibility based solutions.

Thanks in advance for your valuable time.